# How get ng-repeat functionality using Kendo Mobile UI DataSource

Tags: angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app, kendo-mobile, kendo-datasource, angular-kendo

The application in which I am working has different levels of data. Using AngularJS ng-repeat I could point to different levels of data and also could iterate through each data and bind to the view. That is something like [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/u8xL0gxe/) (Here I have used **Kendo Mobile UI** and also **AngularJS**).

According to Telerik documentation **"ng-repeat"** should not be used as CSS styles while using Kendo widgets goes for a toss and also to update the model it gives a problem. To prevent this **Kendo DataSource** should be used to fetch the data from a **JSON string or file**

I tried the same app in the above link with **Kendo DataSource**, but I was able to fetch only 1st level of data from the JSON string. For the second and third level, if I specify the array position, I get only that data on the view something like this link [(With Kendo DataSource and AngularJS)](https://jsfiddle.net/98032cr8/).

So my question is, how to handle multiple levels of JSON Data of this sort

```
 [
    {
        "continentName": "Asia",
        "countries": [
            {
                "countryName": "India",
                "states": [
                  {
                    "stateName": "Sikkim"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Karnataka"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Kerla"
                  },
                ],
            },
            {
                "countryName": "China",
                "states": [
                  {
                    "stateName": "Jiangsu Province"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Heilongjiang Province"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Fujian Province"
                  },
                ],
            },
          ],
    },
        {
        "continentName": "Europe",
        "countries": [
            {
                "countryName": "Germany",
                "states": [
                  {
                    "stateName": "Berlin"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Hesse"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Rhineland-Palatinate"
                  },
                ],
            },
            {
                "countryName": "Denmark",
                "states": [
                  {
                    "stateName": "Hovedstaden"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Midtjylland"
                  },
                  {
                    "stateName": "Nordjylland"
                  },
                ],
            },
          ],
    },       

]
```

To fetch the data using Kendo DataSource

```
angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: json,
    pageSize: 10
});
});
```

In the view section that is html file

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div kendo-list-view k-data-source="source">
            <div k-template>

                <ul class="ulClass">
                    <h3>{{dataItem.continentName}}</h3>
                    <li>
                        {{dataItem.countries[0].countryName}}
                        <ul>
                            <li>{{dataItem.countries[0].states[0].stateName}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So the problem is **how to handle multiple level JSON data and bind to view or templates using Kendo DataSource?**